# Does an Iraqi citizen need a visa to travel from Iraq to Istanbul, Turkey?

Tags: visas, air-travel, turkey, iraqi-citizens

Does an Iraqi citizen need a visa to travel from Iraq to Istanbul, Turkey ?

Comment: Going to Istanbul just to visit .. Site seeing..

Comment: Can an iraqi citizen visit the USA as long as he has passport and visa

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you need a visa** if you're going for a visit.

The [Turkish Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) lists requirements for each country:

> Iraq: Ordinary and official passport holders are required to have visa
>   to enter Turkey. Ordinary passport holders with a valid Schengen
>   members or USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit may get their
>   single entry e-Visas valid for one month e-Visas via the website
>   www.evisa.gov.tr, provided that they meet certain conditions.

If you're just [transiting](http://www.emirates.com/ca/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=IQ&NV=Iraq&DC=FI&DV=Finland&TC=TR&TV=Turkey&h=85294d407d967d80acdfdd2519dd553c412c426d) and have proof of onward travel in less than 24h you may transit without a visa (that means not leaving the airport though)

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a
>   max. transit time of 24 hours.

Note that if you have an S series passport Turkey will automatically refuse you entry